# Rendering the extension "html" to "html" didn't do anything

Tags: docpad

When generating docpad I get lots of warnings with the same message:

```
warning: Rendering the extension "html" to "html" on "docpad-text-plugin.html.html" didn't do anything.
Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
```

I tried searching for files with a double html extension, but found nothing. What is this warning and should I do something about it?

The blog itself generates okay.

Comment: you have it somewhere on github so I can take a look? maybe you used somewhere <t> tag with html.html?

Comment: @LukaszGornicki just uploaded it to GitHub for the first time. [Here is is](https://github.com/AntZoo/blog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of error usually appears if you want to render html content to html using text plugin. So you have something like some html.

Just remove the render part and case is fixed. I've already made a pull request to your project with the fix.

Cheers
Lukasz